# sort concurrent map entries by value

Tags: java, sorting, collections, concurrency

Is there any way to create a thread-safe implementation of `Map` that maintains it's entries sorted by value? I know I can create a thread-safe `Map` like this

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Double> rankings = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>();
```

And I can then get the entries sorted by value by passing it to a utility method like this:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    });

    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

But what I'm looking for is a thread-safe `Map` that *maintains* the entries sorted by value, so that I don't have to call a method such as the above after every insertion/removal in order to keep the entries sorted by value. I guess I'm looking for an implementation that combines the behavior of `ConcurrentHashMap` and `LinkedHashMap`, but haven't found one yet.

[ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) almost provides what I want, but it only seems to support sorting by key value.

Comment: In your use-case, can you restrict the problem to *unique* values, or do you sometimes get duplicate values? If you do have duplicate values, do you have further sorting constraints?

Comment: Also, please clarify -- do you wanted *sorted* or *ordered*? A LinkedHashMap gives you ordered, but not sorted.

Comment: um.....what's the difference between sorted and ordered?

Comment: @Dilum I could eliminate the possibility of duplicate map values if necessary

Comment: Suppose you add "three", "two", "one" in that order to an empty LinkedHashSet. If you iterate over the elements, they will return in that same order. That is *ordered* -- they return in some predictable, meaningful manner. If you added the same to a TreeSet using the default comparator, they would return as "one", "three", "two". Once again predictable and meaningful, but also *sorted* because the insertion order has no bearing. If you were to add the elements to a HashSet, the ordering of the elements would not be predictable.

Answer (score 2):

Consider building a composite data structure for this. At a high level, do the following.

First, implement Map.Entry to keep key-value pairs. The pair's ordering would be first by value, and then by key.

```
private static class InternalEntry<K extends Comparable<K>,
                                   V extends Comparable<V>>
        implements Comparable<InternalEntry<K, V>>,
                   Map.Entry<K, V> {
    private final K _key;
    private final V _val;

    InternalEntry(K key, V val) {
        _key = key;
        _val = val;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return _key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return _val;
    }

    public V setValue(V value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public int compareTo(InternalEntry<K, V> o) {
        int first = _val.compareTo(o._val);
        if (first != 0) {
            return first;
        }
        return _key.compareTo(o._key);
    }
}
```

The entire entry can be used as the *key* of an ordered map.

But that map does not support efficient lookup of value by key. To achieve that, introduce *another* map, which maps keys to entries.

The composite structure looks like this:

```
class OrderedByValue<K extends Comparable<K>, V extends Comparable<V>> {
    private final Map<InternalEntry<K, V>, Boolean> _ordering = 
        new TreeMap<InternalEntry<K, V>, Boolean>();

    private final Map<K, InternalEntry<K, V>> _lookup = 
        new HashMap<K, InternalEntry<K, V>>();

    public V put(K key, V val) {
        InternalEntry<K, V> entry = new InternalEntry<K, V>(key, val);
        InternalEntry<K, V> old = _lookup.put(key, entry);
        if (old == null) {
            _ordering.put(entry, Boolean.TRUE);
            return null;
        }
        _ordering.remove(old);
        _ordering.put(entry, Boolean.TRUE);
        return old.getValue();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public Iterable<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        Iterable entries = Collections.unmodifiableSet(_ordering.keySet());
        return (Iterable<Map.Entry<K, V>>) entries;
    }
}
```

Note that I've not supplied all the necessary code to implement a full Map -- let me know if you need help with the other methods.

You also need to do some special case code in the InternalEntry's comparison implementation if null keys/values need to be supported.

Comment: @Dave, I've left it up to you to switch TreeMap, LinkedHashMap with their concurrent brethren.